# Hide index.php from URL when using both index.html and index.php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, .htaccess

I have a website using both index.html and index.php. index.html is an age restriction splash page and when clicking yes on a button you get re-directed to the main site, using index.php, which is a onepage scroller without any /subdomains.

What I would like to do is to, when you've been redirected to index.php, is to hide the index.php of the example.com/index.php URL ... I have searched the entire web but have yet to find a solution that works.

Modifying the .htaccess hasn't worked, I don't think any of the codes out there do what I want (and I haven't managed to write one myself). I've tried using iFrame with JavaScript but it's hard to find a working solution. The closes I've come is using DirectoryIndex for index.php but then of course index.html won't work.

I am sure that there is an easy solution to this but that I'm thinking about it the wrong way. How would I go about solving this?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: You have to provide some of your code in order for us to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this would be to add the following to your `.htaccess` file:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
```

This will use `index.php` as the default index file. Inside the php file you could then do something like this to display `index.html` the first time the user is going to your site:

```
// start a new session and check if the index.html have been included
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['index_included'])) {
  // display the index.html and exit script
  // notice that we are setting index_included to true in our session
  include_once('index.html');
  $_SESSION['index_included'] = 1;
  exit;
}
// rest of your php goes here
```

If you would like to mark that the user has clicked a button in `index.html`you could do this using ajax:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Sample Index.html</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
// index.html
$(document).ready(function() {
  //
  $('#button').click(function() {
    // make an ajax request to index.php to tell that the button
    // is clicked
    $.ajax('index.php', {
      type : 'post',
      data : 'clicked=true',
      success:function() {
        // reload the location to send user to index.php
        window.location.reload();
      }
    });
    return false;
  });
});
</script>
<body>
  <a href="#" id="button">click me</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Then in `index.php` you trap the ajax call and set a session variable like this:

```
// index.php
session_start();
// if we receive an ajax request we mark this in the session
if(isset($_POST['clicked'])) {
   $_SESSION['clicked'] = true;
   exit;
}
if(!isset($_SESSION['clicked'])) {
  // since the user hasn't clicked the button in index.html yet
  // we include that file 
  include_once('index.html');
  exit;
}
// rest of your php code which only gets executed if $_SESSION['clicked'] is set
```

As an alternative you could use `setcookie()` instead of storing the status in a session. Something like this should work:

```
// index.php
if(isset($_POST['clicked'])) {
  setcookie('clicked', true);
  exit;
}
if(!isset($_COOKIE['clicked'])) {
  include_once('index.html');
  exit;
}
// rest of index.php
```

Comment: Should be checking if they clicked on the 'I am the appropriate age for this content' button. Not just if they visited the index.html page.

Comment: @greg_diesel - I understand that, I'm just pointing out that he can do it this way, by setting something in a session through php. How this is done in this particular case it's up to him. For instance you could make an ajax request to index.php when the user does something in index.html and set some variable.

Comment: @greg_diesel - The point is that it is one file that handles all requests. I could update my post and give and real example if you don't understand?

Answer (score 0):

You could look into your `php.ini` file and add the `expose_php = off` statement. 
Although I never tried it, I think it's what you're looking for.

This [link](http://php.net/manual/en/security.hiding.php#64278) might also have some extra tips on how to mask the extensions you're using as something they aren't.

**----- UPDATE -----**

After reading the answer Cyclone gave and since it represents a solution to a completely different problem than what I thought your question was, I reread your question again and feel I gave you the wrong answer. However I'll let it stay up there just in case I might have misread a second time.

So if you're trying to hide `index.php` from the link `http://example.com/index.php` there's no real way of making that disappear completely as the user might type it in or get there from a link that had it written. However you can redirect to `http://example.com/` instead of `http://example.com/index.php`.

Given you have both `index.html` and `index.php` this would only work if you used Cyclone's answer to call `index.html` from within `index.php` and have it not appear a second time.